# alarm with mathematical problems

Tags: python

I am using python to create an alarm clock which asks mathematical problems.But my problem is I want to continue asking questions if the user gives wrong answer.Please Help me with that.I am using tkinter to create alarm clock.But in the askyesno,yes and no only yes is executing.So please help me to improve the code

```
enter code here
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import os
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Alarm clock")
def SubmitButton():
 AlarmTime= enter1.get()
 Message1()
 CurrentTime = time.strftime("%H:%M")
 print("the alarm time is: {}".format(AlarmTime))
 while AlarmTime != CurrentTime:
  CurrentTime = time.strftime("%H:%M")
  time.sleep(1)
  x = 0
  y = 0
 while AlarmTime == CurrentTime:
    if x == 0:
         x+=1
         os.system("start alarm-music.mp3")
    if y<1:
         label2.config(text = "Alarm music playing.....")
         messagebox.showinfo(title= 'Alarm Message', message= "  {}".format(enter2.get()))

    while True:
         if y<1:
            messagebox.askquestion("answer the question in yes or no","(9^5)-1+(4|3)=18",icon='question')
            y+=1
         if True:
            break                
         else:

           os.system("start alarm-music.mp3")
           messagebox.askyesno("answer the        question","9*71=647",icon='question')
           if True:
             sys.close()
           else:
             os.system("start alarm-music.mp3")

       def Message1():
       AlarmTimeLable= enter1.get()
       label2.config(text="the Alarm time is Counting...")
       messagebox.showinfo(title = 'Alarm clock', message = 'Alarm will Ring at {}'.format(AlarmTimeLable))     
       alarm1 = ttk.Frame(root)
       alarm1.pack()
       alarm1.config(height = 200, width = 200)

       alarmtime1= ttk.Label(alarm1,text = "Enter the Alarm time :")
       alarmtime1.pack()


       enter1 = ttk.Entry(alarm1, width = 100)
       enter1.pack()
       enter1.insert(3,"Please enter 24-hr format here")

       AlarmMessage= ttk.Label(alarm1, text="Alarm Message:")
       AlarmMessage.pack()

       enter2= ttk.Entry(alarm1, width=100)
       enter2.pack()

       button1= ttk.Button(alarm1, text= "submit", command=SubmitButton)
       button1.pack()
       label2= ttk.Label(alarm1)
       label2.pack()



       root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
if True:
        break
```

always breaks your cycle. To avoid this try to save result of dialog to any variable and then validate it value:

```
if y<1:
   answer = messagebox.askquestion("answer the question in yes or no","(9^5)-1+(4|3)=18",icon='question')
   y+=1
   if answer == 'yes':
       break
...
answer = messagebox.askyesno("answer the question","9*71=647",icon='question')
if answer  == True:
    sys.close()
else:
    os.system("start alarm-music.mp3")
...
```

Comment: I also want to askquestion and recieve answer from the user.So i created a dictionary but In tkinter Label is not reading the question.Please help me with that

Comment: @AbhiramReddy if you need to receive string from users you can use askstring() http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm

Comment: I want to ask the question randomnly from a dictionary.I used StringVar() but it's not reading the value from the dictionary.

Comment: @AbhiramReddy try to change list to this: `l=['328*89+5679','716*92+8355','710*59+8937','992*72+8541','992*78+8541','422*61+3596']` strings as value.

Comment: I changed it but it is still not working.It is not still reading the string.

Comment: @AbhiramReddy sorry cannot help you then.